# Cancel consecutive commands in cmd.exe in Windows 10

Tags: command-line

I've copy pasted to cmd.exe these lines:

```
 copy_table1.bat
 copy_table2.bat
```

Execution takes long time, so I want to tell `CMD.exe` to complete `copy_table1.bat` and stop, but not start `copy_table2.bat`.

I can use ctrl-c, but this will kill current process `copy_table1.bat`. Is there a way to stop after `copy_table1.bat` but before 1copy_table2.bat`?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to ensure that `copy_table2.bat` no longer exists.

So rename it temporarily until `copy_table1.bat` finishes, then return it.

In the future, you might add a `pause` command between the two, to decide whether to
continue.

Comment: In my case it is more like `ogr2ogr -flag1` followed by `ogr2ogr -flag2`. So, I cannot rename it.